# Глючит клавиатура, мышь и др. при работе на ноутбуке

Tags: клавиатура, mouse-event

Сразу после утсановки **Windows** или **Ubuntu** возникают странные глюки на ноутбуке. Если что-то начать печатать например в консоли, то ли в браузере, то буквы печатаются то большие, то маленькие, как угодно.

Что касается работы с мышью: если выделить мышкой папку или файл, то они выделяются несколько сразу и выделение не уходит если его отменить например, нажав по пустому месту рабочего стола.

Также заходил в **Bios** и там нельзя было ничего сделать совсем, только сигнал поступал при нажатии любой клавиши, стрелки на клавиатуре. И такие странности возникают периодически, не при каждом включении компьютера. Они могут возникнуть через 2 часа работы с ноутбуком, либо же сразу при включении его.

На вирусы тестировал уже.

Ноутбук **Lenovo Thinkpad Carbon X1**

Comment: Залипла клавиатура, вероятно.

Comment: ну не только ж клавиатура глючит, мышь тоже

Comment: Ага, тот же SHIFT на мышу никак не влияет, разумеется.

Comment: точно, это SHIFT. Даже ещё такое дело было: когда был открыт браузер Chrome, но свёрнут, то чтоб развернуть я щёлкал по нему , но при этом открывалась новая пустая страница. Это происходит при Shift+левая клавиша мыши. Ок. Но как теперь полечить это? Это на программном уровне или что-то может быть с самой клавишей Shift, точнее одной из двух?

Comment: Вам уже написано: залипла клавиатура. Не программа глючит, а клавиатура залипла. Или мать глючит, но менее вероятно.

Comment: Я понял что залипла клавиатура на ноутбуке. Но а что делать теперь? Отключить функцию клавиш или разбирать ноут?

Comment: Отключить функцию *залипания клавиш имел ввиду

Comment: В сервис несите

Comment: я для начала отключил функцию залипания клавиш(снял галочки) в Windows 7 - Панель Управления - Центр Специальных возможностей - Облегчение работы с клавиатурой. А если это повториться в Ubuntu, Кто знает как там  сделать подобную процедуру?

Comment: уже наконец сам нашёл. Если у кого возникнет проблема такая же, то вот http://vbbook.ru/linux/chto-esli-ploxo-rabotaet-klaviatyra-ubuntu-/ или http://kubuntu.ru/node/3311